# Android SDK manager fails, if launched from Eclipse

Tags: android, sdk

Has anyone seen this problem?

I'm in the middle of updating my SDK to add Android 2.2, on my Mac.
You don't have to download the entire SDK -- there is a tool already on your system which can download just the extra parts of Adroid 2.2  This page explains: http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html

The tool is called the "Android SDK and AVD manager".    There are two ways to start this tool.

1. You can start it from within Eclipse, via: Window > "Android SDK and AVD Manager"

or

2. You can start it from the command line, via  cd /tools ; ./android &

To my surprise, the tool is slightly different, when started from the different places.  In particular, starting it from Eclipse, and pressing the "Available Packages" button, did NOT show the new Android 2.2 release.  Starting it from the command line *does* show the new Android 2.2 release, and enables me to install it.

It's very easy to install the 2.2 update, but you have to start the SDK manager from the command line on Mac.  It looks like all the downloads will take a hour or two.

Has anyone else noticed this problem, and what is the place to report Android tools bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Go back to eclipse and try replacing the https in the link to http.  A lot of people have had to do that.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, and that was my first thought, too.

Then I noticed that the command line tool was quite happily using https protocol to access and find new things in the repository.  

There is some difference between launching in Eclipse and launch from the command line, which causes SDK manager to fail to find the new API in the first place.   

Is there a webpage to report bugs to Google?

Comment: http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

That is for reporting bugs.  I think its more of an eclipse problem though.  Did you actually try doing the replace?  There is some really strange behavior in Eclipse when handling these things.